# Do troops gained as council rewards have Iron Will advantages?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Just taking a council request mission and the reward is a new soldier, of rank Major.

Do these "reward" troops get the Iron Will bonus & so have the higher will-power?

Comment: This is one that's hard to confirm, but I don't believe that they do.

Comment: Yeah, hard to confirm. I've almost always chosen missions with engineers as reward, because that's the most logical strategy.

Comment: I'd have to test but I'd be surprised if they don't...they don't come fully promoted, you have to pick their skills, so I'd expect it to be as if they earned the promotions in your base in other aspects as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they do. I took two of them in my last game, and they immediately had the highest will of my squad. They later became the first to get psi powers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but with limited gains. A new Major ranked soldier never got more than 100 willpower with many reloads. But a Major I train myself can have a maximum of 112 willpower.